# Export Entourage Database files

Tags: email, ms-office, office-365

I have a customer who has used Entourage 2008 on High Sierra for his email. Entourage 2008 has since stopped working. So I can't natively export to mbox.

I have since installed office 365 for his use - but it will only import from Outlook 2011.

I tried installing office 2011 for mac to do the import and it will not install.

I have the database file just no way to export from it. Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question totally confused me.  I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here.  It looks like this started with Entourage 2008 not working so have you contacted that developer about their application and their database?

Comment: this (https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office-for-mac/outlook-for-mac/upgrade-from-entourage-2008-or-2004-to-outlook-2011-for-mac/)
 may help